# Android phonegap - using youtube iframe - leave a blue square when I click back

Tags: android, youtube, cordova

The scenario:
**I open my app, I click on a screen that has a youtube embeded iframe,
I click play, a blue square is displayed on top of the iframe.**
[image]

**I click back, the app goes to the previous screen but the blue square remains**
[image]
why does it display this blue square?

how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it displays that blue square is to notify the user what link/interactive object the user has clicked. This is built into the the browser so a user knows which link they clicked, particularly on older websites when the links are close together.

If you want to remove the blue outline from all elements add this to your stylesheet:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

If you want to only remove the blue box on the video, apply the above style to the youtube embed.